# Search an array with variable column sizes java

Tags: java

I want to display some of the content of the .txt file on the screen after copying it into a new file. The content of the text file is not exactly the same structure throughout.

When i did this

```
if (m[11].equals("Channel") && m[12].equals("ID")){ System.out.println("Wavelenght ID = " + m[9]);
```

I got an error array out of bounds.

> TESTSTEP: DEBUG *** Fpga Config ECFG ***:  EED                           3 : Channel ID

If this line was found i want it to display Wavelenght ID = 3

```
String p = path.replace("\\", "\\\\");
    File file = new File(p);
    File[]   files = file.listFiles();
    BufferedReader inputStream = null;
    PrintWriter outputStreamI = null;
    PrintWriter outputStreamO = null;

    try {
        String l,c;
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++){

            inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(files[i].getAbsolutePath()));
            outputStreamI = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("S:\\WRED_IBP\\" + files[i].getName().replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "")+ "Ingress.txt"));
            outputStreamO = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("S:\\WRED_IBP\\" +files[i].getName().replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "")+ "Egress.txt"));  

            while ((l = inputStream.readLine())!= null) {
                String[] m=l.split(" ");
                for(int d=0; d<m.length; d++){ 
                    c=m[d];
                    if (c.equalsIgnoreCase("ied_wred") ){outputStreamI.println(l); if (outputStreamI.checkError()){System.err.println("Error in output stream");}} //|| c.equalsIgnoreCase("WARNING") || c.equals("ERROR")
                    else if (c.equalsIgnoreCase("eed_brc_ibp")){outputStreamO.println(l); if (outputStreamO.checkError()){System.err.println("Error in output stream");}} // || c.equalsIgnoreCase("WARNING") || c.equals("ERROR") 
                }   
            }
        }

    } catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }//wait(10);
    finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try{ inputStream.close();} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}}
        if (outputStreamI != null) {outputStreamI.close();}
        if (outputStreamO != null) {outputStreamO.close();}

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
if (m.length > 12 && m[11].equals("Channel") && m[12].equals("ID")){ 
    System.out.println("Wavelenght ID = " + m[9]);
}
```

So index out of bound won't happen here.

Make sure you put these lines before the `for` loop.

Comment: i have tried that it still tells me java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11. The first line would have only about 3 columns the code terminates here and catches the exception

Comment: Are you sure the exception is from this line? are you sure you used the exact line I used? the order does matter.

Comment: Yes I'm sure the exception is from this line and i used the exact code Copied and pasted. I put the code after the split method `while ((l = inputStream.readLine())!= null) {
     String[] m=l.split(" ");
     if (m.length > 8 && m[11].equals("Channel") && m[12].equals("ID")){ 
         System.out.println("Wavelenght ID = " + m[9]);
     }`

Comment: sorry forgot i changed the number. 12 just skips that line totally nothing is printed out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`TESTSTEP: DEBUG * Fpga Config ECFG *: EED 3 : Channel ID`

I'm assuming this is the text in the file. When you read this, you are trying to split it based on spaces. What you should be doing is split it based on `:`.

Comment: there are some lines that dont have `:` and i do different things there. The space is the more general separation that works for all. Thanx